Установка chrome-gnome, OC Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell

В Линукс первый день... Вычитала что chrome-gnome может объединить верхнюю и нижнюю панель.
OC Ubuntu, собственно выполнила данную команду. Установила, все ок.
Только что делать дальше, где это приложение, в настройках все тоже самое...
Как мне объединить верхнюю и нижнюю панель?


Почему в заголовке один вопрос, а в тексте другой? Покажи скрин что там у тебя с панелями

Прикрепила, все стандартно

"Вычитала что chrome-gnome может объединить верхнюю и нижнюю панель." - приводите цитату и ссылку на первоисточник. А чтоб панель задач осталась одна стоит поменять окружение рабочего стола с гнома на что-то получше, хотя бы на kde (лучше было бы стразу поставить вместо убунты кубунту).

Установите расширение dash-to-panel через пакетный менеджер или через сайт extensions.gnome.org (chrome-gnome-shell на этом сайте позволяет включить расширение сразу)
Откройте приложение Расширения включите dash-to-panel и отключите ubuntu-dock
